# Google-RISC security event is not getting fired for my app (Google singin)

Tags: php, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I have implemented google oauth(successfully) login and google RISC security event handling for our app. To enable oauth, I have created web app on google console using `"API AND SERVICES" -> Service account.`

```
**STEPS i followed:-**

**1. Create authorization token(JWT).
**2. Call the RISC stream configuration API**

**Eg. code:-**


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "delivery": {
            "delivery_method": "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/delivery-method/push",
            "url": "https://v4.api.indev.proofhub.com/kvsigninjwt/webhooks/Eventshook/validateSecurityEventToken"
        },
        "events_requested": [
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/sessions-revoked",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/sessions-revoked",
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/all-token-revoked",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/oauth/event-type/tokens-revoked",
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/account-disabled",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-disabled",
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/account-enabled",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-enabled",
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/account-credential-change-required",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-credential-change-required",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/verification",
            "https://accounts.google.com/risc/event/one-token-revoked",
            "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/oauth/event-type/token-revoked"
        ]
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGVzaWduaW50ZXN0QHByb29maHViLWluZGV2LTYyMTc0LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU3MTk3OTQ1LCJpc3MiOiJnb29nbGVzaWduaW50ZXN0QHByb29maHViLWluZGV2LTYyMTc0LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3Jpc2MuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb21cL2dvb2dsZS5pZGVudGl0eS5yaXNjLnYxYmV0YS5SaXNjTWFuYWdlbWVudFNlcnZpY2UiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTcxOTQzNDV9.gInolH2RXayGyFsmsSy6ACP-xiXjopb5hb6r0cEwpmqI6WPJNBtpG8j7ez1xFQyjmFuLhRE1JtUy2qBTeK8zH2RPBfnfVjgaJ1RrDi1ppaK_5-WShOz2mbM9rjZxVwJWKREn3DUNFZVMc194WJA-hWpvm_-omhOJxo1ukp5HQIHjwpNqR2a_zJOHBcJnDC6W0GNwq19ISE-nRMRP8BV6NUlrBnBuVzy1MB_wTYyfo-V44hrEkBUM0WWYKVhctCJST0qOqLzUPRerAWbeMOrwTm6lq6pTNmNvbuPp9YZpcuznOiEHgR2yTDGUDWcOzuCxpj0NFcILgnJ7RRLHq2UA9Q',
        'Host: risc.googleapis.com',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


**3. Verified on https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify**
```

**Query:-** How to receive Events from google account(logged in using google signin).?

Comment: Why do you think events are not being triggered if you tested the verification event? Did you receive the verification event?

Comment: Yes, But the other events didn't triggered on mentioned Endpoint.

Comment: The other events can only be triggered if the event occurs, so only if an account is disabled that is also connected to your app. Do you have some test users you have tried it out with?